# enable middlename in registration form in magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

How to enable middlename in registration form in magento 2.2.4?
Also when can i find customer attributes in Magento2.2.4 Admin. How to make customer attributes visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below path to enable middle name in registration form.

> Go to **Admin >> Store >> Configurations >> Customers >> Customers
>   Configurations >> Name And Address Options (Tab) >> Show Middle Name
>   (initial) change dropdown to** **Yes**

Comment: i did that still not able to see

Comment: Please check clear cache after admin changes

Comment: I cleared cache and tried still no success

Comment: do you have custom registration form or default magento form ?

Comment: default magento form. I have migrated data from m1 to m2. Do you know how to see customer attributes in M2 2.2.4?

Comment: there is no option in magento 2 to show custom customer attribute as per product attributes, but you can check customer attributes in customer edit form, if any attribute enables. if you not found any then please check into database eav_attribute table.

Comment: @Arjun did you get the solution ?

Comment: I cleared the entire cache, changed Yes & No and save the data. Finally it worked